# FullSimplify gives wrong answer when operating on HypergeometricPFQ

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

When I try to simplify this hypergeometric function

```
FullSimplify[HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2 - n/2}, {-(1/2) - n/2}, -a^2]]
```

*Mathematica* 10.0.1.0 returns

```
(Exp[-a^2] (1 + n + 2 a^2))/(1 + n)
```

but if I compare the two expressions for different integer values of `n`,

```
Table[(Exp[-a^2] (1 + 2 a^2 + n))/(1 + n) ==
      HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2 - n/2}, {-(1/2) - n/2}, -a^2], {n, 0, 6}]
```

they are different for odd `n`

```
{True, 1/2 (2 + 2 a^2) E^-a^2 == 1, True, 1/4 (4 + 2 a^2) E^-a^2 == 1 - a^2/2,
 True, 1/6 (6 + 2 a^2) E^-a^2 == 1 - (2 a^2)/3 + a^4/6, True}
```

What's going on?

(This behavior persists if I use `FunctionExpand[]` in place of `FullSimplify[]`, since the latter calls the former.)

Comment: Simply put: `Hypergeometric1F1[]` degenerates to a polynomial if its upper parameter is a nonpositive integer. Unfortunately, the generic solution returned by `FunctionExpand[]`/`FullSimplify[]` does not take this into account.

Comment: Are you saying that the result returned by `FunctionExpand[]` is false when the upper parameter is a nonpositive integer?

Comment: Pretty much, yes, due to the exponential factor not being taken care of. If you're interested, I can write a solution detailing how to derive the correct result in that special case.

Comment: Terrifying.  Yes, I would be very grateful for a solution.  The hypergeometric function is a series coefficient in a Taylor expansion I am working with, for which I really need a simple expression that I can further operate on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To recap, the result returned by `FunctionExpand[Hypergeometric1F1[1/2 - n/2, -(1/2) - n/2, -a^2]]` is a *generic* solution, which is intended to be correct in most cases. Unfortunately, the case of odd `n` is not part of those cases:

```
Table[Hypergeometric1F1[1/2 - n/2, -(1/2) - n/2, -a^2] == 
      Exp[-a^2] (1 + 2 a^2 + n)/(1 + n) // FullSimplify // TrueQ, {n, 10}]
   {False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True}
```

To handle the odd `n` case, we first do a preliminary transformation:

```
Hypergeometric1F1[1/2 - n/2, -(1/2) - n/2, -a^2] /. n -> 2 k + 1 // Simplify
   Hypergeometric1F1[-k, -1 - k, -a^2]
```

which shows the source of the failure: the case of odd `n` results in a Kummer function with a nonpositive numerator parameter, which is precisely the degenerate polynomial case. To explicitly deal with this, we go back to the defining series for ${}_1 F_1$:

$${}_1 F_1\left({{a}\atop{b}}\mid z\right)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(a)_j}{(b)_j}\frac{z^j}{j!}$$

For the special case under consideration, we have

$${}_1 F_1\left({{-k}\atop{-1-k}}\mid -a^2\right)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-k)_j}{(-1-k)_j}\frac{\left(-a^2\right)^j}{j!}$$

Since $(-k)_j=0$ if $j>k$, the series terminates:

$${}_1 F_1\left({{-k}\atop{-1-k}}\mid -a^2\right)=\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{(-k)_j}{(-1-k)_j}\frac{\left(-a^2\right)^j}{j!}$$

Using

```
FullSimplify[Pochhammer[-k, j]/Pochhammer[-1 - k, j]]
   1 - j/(1 + k)
```

we thus have

```
Sum[(1 - j/(1 + k)) (-a^2)^j/j!, {j, 0, k}] // FullSimplify
   ((-a)^k a^(4 + k) E^a^2 + (1 + a^2 + k) Gamma[2 + k, -a^2])/
   (E^a^2 (1 + k)*Gamma[2 + k])
```

We can now undo the earlier substitution:

```
s[n_] = % /. k -> (n - 1)/2 // FullSimplify
   (2 ((-a)^((-1 + n)/2) a^((7 + n)/2) E^a^2 + ((1 + 2 a^2 + n)
    Gamma[(3 + n)/2, -a^2])/2))/(E^a^2 (1 + n) Gamma[(3 + n)/2])
```

The rather complicated closed form gives no indication that it is in fact a polynomial. Nevertheless,

```
Table[Hypergeometric1F1[1/2 - n/2, -(1/2) - n/2, -a^2] == s[n] // 
      FullSimplify, {n, 1, 11, 2}]
   {True, True, True, True, True, True}

s[7] // FullSimplify
   (24 - 18*a^2 + 6*a^4 - a^6)/24
```

Comment: Tremendously helpful. Am I crazy in calling this a bug, since the hypergeometric function was returned by SeriesCoefficient[], which is expected to use integers? Is there any way to avoid incorrect simplifications by FullSimplify[] in the future that doesn't require detailed knowledge of the relevant special function?

Comment: Again, by design, the results obtained by simplification functions are only [*generically* correct](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GenericAndNonGenericSolutions.html). It is entirely possible to have a result that is not valid for a countable set of values. Thus, it is always in your best interest to perform sanity checks on whatever results you get, whether in *Mathematica* or a different CAS.